# ipython notebook how to troubleshoot stall - both firefox and chrome

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

This is my first question. I usually find my answers by searching but not this time. I'm learning python and running the ipython (py 2.7) notebook locally. I started with the qtconsole and that worked fine until I needed to work with some different libraries specifically for notebook.

Originally, I was using Chrome and had issues with being stalled: "In [*]". I tried adjusting my port and firewall settings as per another post but to no avail.

I then switched to firefox and it worked consistently. Until today. I want to know how to troubleshoot these issues as they occur. If anyone can give me suggestions I would appreciate it.

- Windows 7 SP1 64bit
- Firefox 35.0.1
- Python 2.7.8 |Anaconda 2.1.0 (64-bit)

Josh

Comment: Did you something specific when this happens, e.g. does it always stall when you are executing a specific function?

Comment: Hi, no unfortunately it is not reliably reproducible. For example, I tried working in notebook today and everything is working. Notepad either stalls on running any cell, or works fine. If I can't reproduce it obviously you can't provide specific help, but is there a good reference available for troubleshooting unexplained stalling?